# How to send a CC in C#. Create a duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I developing an app which is an email generator, the thing is that I need to send a carbon copy of my email to the same email I am using to send the original one, basically I need to duplicate every email. But when I set the cc email the code simply ignores the CC.

C# Code:

```
const string fromPassword = "password";
string subject = "Subject " + sXmlArray[0].ToString();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
//Google SMTP Host
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@domain.com", fromPassword);
smtp.Timeout = 100000;
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
message.Subject = subject;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = StrContent.ToString();

//Carbon Copy
//HERE IS THE ISSUE
MailAddress CarbonCopy = new MailAddress("myEmail@domain.com");
message.CC.Add(CarbonCopy);
smtp.Send(message);
```

Why the code ignores this piece of code? If I declare a different email it works fine? 
Can somebody help me out with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's general behavior of any email system.  Even though you add the same address multiple times in `To`, `Cc`, and `Bcc`, it just delivers only one.  In order to duplicate you need to send this email twice with your logic.  So, the brute way it to add another `smtp.Send(message);`

Comment: Sure, that'd be only way then. Thanks!

Comment: As workaround, you could try using a different display name (e.g. use `new MailAddress("myEmail@domain.com","Another Copy")`) or perhaps try changing the one of the letters from lowercase to uppercase in the address itself.  It *might* work.